# Why can't my WndProc be in a class?

Tags: c++, winapi

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward. I have my class:

```
class Simple
{
public:
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         ...
    }
};
```

and my `WinMain`:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR commandLine, int cmdShow)
{
    Simple *simple = new Simple();
    ...

    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = simple->WndProc;
    ...
 }
```

When I try though, I get:

```
error C2440: '=' :cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall Simple::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'
```

Is there any reason I can't have my `WndProc` in a class? Seems like that would be really useful.

Comment: Why do you think having the `WindowProc` function as a member is really useful? What instance of the class would this member function operate on?

Comment: That's a really bad way to use `new`. Use stack allocation.

Comment: @chris. I didn't initially. I just thought maybe if it was on the heap, that would fix it. `Debug-by-prayer` approach.

Comment: @Praetorian, I get what you're saying. Since the solution seems to be 'make it static' I think that makes sense. ALSO, I'm totally new to win32.

Comment: I would stay away from it until you have a firm grasp of the language.

Comment: @chris- I actually think this would be a good use case for `new`, since if the object is supposed to be attached to a window, it would need to outlive the function call that created it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

C++ treats member functions and free functions differently - member functions need to have access to a `this` pointer, and typically that's passed in as a hidden first parameter.  Consequently, an n-argument member function would be most similar to an (n+1)-argument free function, which means that code trying to call your `WndProc` would pass in the wrong number of arguments.

You can, however, declare `WndProc` as a `static` member function, which eliminates the `this` pointer.  This code should work:

```
class Simple
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         ...
    }
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR commandLine, int cmdShow)
{
    Simple *simple = new Simple();
    ...

    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = simple->WndProc;
    ...
 }
```

Of course, this means you can't directly access the fields of the class.  You could get around this by embedding a pointer to the class into the extra bytes reserved for each window instance, perhaps by using [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Once you've done that, you can recover the receiver object pointer by writing something like this:

```
class Simple
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         Simple* me = reinterpret_cast<Simple*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
         if (me) return me->realWndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
         return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
private:
    LRESULT CALLBACK realWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         // Yay!  I'm a member function!
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, this miraculously worked! Very very awesome and much better than the singleton approaches I've seen. I simply added this line after creating the HWND: SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (long)this);

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work at all. static_cast<Simple*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)); returned null.

Comment: @IanYoung Had you previously called SetWindowLongPointer to set the data?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes I did. I suspect that's where it's failing. It's probably due to not being called at the correct time. When should I be doing it?

Comment: @IanYoung You need to do this right after you create the window and before you begin processing any messages.

Comment: @IanYoung You should probably ask this as a standalone question, since that way you can provide more of your actual code and get lots of pairs of eyes on it. I doubt I can help you debug things in the comments.

Comment: @templatetypedef It's ok, I found a much simpler way of doing it. I passed in the wndprc function as a parameter into the class which creates the window. As the class is a high level application object, It's the only thing referenced in main, so I use it as a global and allow wndprc to send the class messages directly. Job done.

Comment: Casts from integral types to pointers should use `reinterpret_cast`, not `static_cast`. ScottyMacDev brought this up in a now-deleted answer, as using `static_cast` here seems to be causing errors in modern VSC++. My edit got rejected, though I don't see how a simple correction "deviates from the original intent of the post". Oh well.

Comment: @ollpu Fixed! I’m surprised that GetWindowLongPtr doesn’t return a void*, where a static_cast would work just fine. Seems like it now returns a large integer.

Comment: Word of caution: the first few messages to the window are sent **before** `CreateWindow[Ex]` returns. So even if you call `SetWindowLongPtr` next thing after `CreateWindow`, `WM_CREATE` and `WM_NCCREATE` won't be handled by the class. MFC uses a thread local pointer to the object (assuming `CreateWindow` won't ever be nested), and sets up the object pointer in the window data in its WM_NCCREATE handler.

Comment: Or you can pass the object pointer as the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow`, and hook the object in the `WM_CREATE` handler via the `((CREATESTRUCT*)lParam)->lpCreateParams`.

Comment: Returns nullptr for me.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a member function has an implicit first parameter of `this`, and so has a different signiture than a pointer to a 'free' function. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Answer (score 1):

```
// Header  
class Foo   
{  
public:
  Foo();   

  ~Foo();  

  static LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

private:
  LRESULT CALLBACK MyWinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

  static Foo *m_pInstance;
}

// Implementation

#include "Foo.h"

Foo * Foo::m_pInstance = NULL;

Foo::Foo()
{  
  m_pInstance = this;   
}  

Foo::~Foo()
{
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Foo::WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
{  
  return m_pInstance->MyWinProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
}  

LRESULT CALLBACK Foo::MyWinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
{  
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
}
```

Comment: can you give a small explanation about what your code is doing?

Comment: What if you have multiple instances of the same class?