# LNK2001 in "How can I make a WNDPROC or DLGPROC a member of my C++ class?"

Tags: c++, class, constructor, wndproc

VS10: MCBS: Hi there,
In the light of this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727015/class-method-for-wndproc/21727297#comment59847597_21727297) encountered a problem attempting a Hello World implementation of Raymond Chen's method in [How can I make a WNDPROC or DLGPROC a member of my C++ class?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140203-00/?p=1893/) using Pudeyev's [code for "Hello World"](http://web.archive.org/web/20050213175157/http://www.rpi.edu/~pudeyo/articles/wndproc/basecode.cpp):

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: long __thiscall
BaseWnd::WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" 
(?WndProc@BaseWnd@@AAEJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
```

The code is as follows:

```
// ...Written by Oleg Pudeyev, (c) 2003
#include <windows.h>
HINSTANCE appHinst;

class BaseWnd
{
public:
BaseWnd();

// This is the static callback that we register
static LRESULT CALLBACK s_WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// The static callback recovers the "this" pointer and then calls this member function.
LRESULT BaseWnd::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

};

BaseWnd::BaseWnd(void)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {
        // Request redraws as we're centering the string
        CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW,
        BaseWnd::s_WndProc,
        // No per-class data
        0,
        // No per-window data
        0,
        appHinst,
        LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION),
        LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW),
        HBRUSH(COLOR_BACKGROUND),
        0,
        L"BaseWnd"
    };
RegisterClassW(&wc);
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(L"BaseWnd", L"Hello, World!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, 0, appHinst, this);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
}

LRESULT BaseWnd::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Umsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (Umsg)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage(0);
break;

case WM_PAINT:
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
RECT r;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
SetBkMode(ps.hdc, TRANSPARENT);
DrawTextW(ps.hdc, L"Hello, World!", -1, &r, DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE);
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
break;

default:
// Use default handling for messages we don't process
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Umsg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK BaseWnd::s_WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
BaseWnd *pThis; // our "this" pointer will go here

if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
// Recover the "this" pointer which was passed as a parameter to CreateWindow(Ex).
LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
pThis = static_cast<BaseWnd*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);
// Put the value in a safe place for future use
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));
} else {
// Recover the "this" pointer from where our WM_NCCREATE handler stashed it.
pThis = reinterpret_cast<BaseWnd*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
}

if (pThis) {
// Now that we have recovered our "this" pointer, let the member function finish the job.
//Removal of this line removes the LNK2001
return pThis->WndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

// "this" pointer unknown, so just do the default thing. Hopefully, didn't need to customize behavior yet.
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hprev, LPTSTR cmdline, int showcmd)
{
appHinst = hinst;
BaseWnd p;
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong with either how the BaseWnd constructor is invoked or the class setup - or perhaps, viz the date on Raymond's article, a revision of c++11 that cannot cope?

Edit: Replaced WndProc with absolute qualifier BaseWnd::WndProc and made the offending static callback a callback. Great, the other issues with the code we can work with.
Edit2: The final piece of the puzzle was returning Pudeyev's original `CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW` to the WNDCLASS structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I think a definition of scope is none.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc
{
　↓
LRESULT CALLBACK BaseWnd::WndProc
{
```

Comment: In this compiler `LRESULT CALLBACK BaseWnd::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Umsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` get's a C2264 error in function definition and a C2373 different type modifiers.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Edit your question and show what you are putting in. Declaration and definition should both be `LRESULT CALLBACK` or they should both be `LRESULT`.

Comment: @Barmak: Thanks, see what you mean about going back to the API. This is tricky stuff.:)

Comment: Oh, In this case, I guess CALLBACK may have been unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be self-explanatory. `BaseWnd::WndProc` is declared, but not defined. See @nariuji

Also `BaseWnd` needs a public constructor because you are going to call it later:

```
class BaseWnd
{
//******* make this public:
public:
BaseWnd();
...
};
```

`WNDCLASSW wc` has to be initialized to zero:

```
WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
```

When you create the window it is invisible. You have to make it visible with `ShowWindow` or change the style to `WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(L"BaseWnd", L"Hello, World!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, 0, appHinst, this);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); //*** add this
```

Declaring a pointer doesn't do anything. You also need a message loop:

```
WinMain(...)
{
    //BaseWnd *pthis; //***remove this line
    BaseWnd wnd;//***add this line
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmak, actually tried those prior to posting. :( Same error. but defining `BaseWnd::WndProc`: what do you suggest?

Comment: It should work, if it gives an error it's a different error. Actually @nariuji picked up the other error. See update.