# (C++)How to use virtual function in Window procedure?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get an event to happen (just testing with a simple message box with random text) for the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message. If it is a member of the same class of the procedure, it works fine - unless it is virtual. Well, that works, but I kind of need it to be virtual so I can implement it in an actual scene.

I tried looking up some stuff, and I didn't really find my exact problem. So, I hope you guys can help me. I don't think I'll need my code in here, since this is a pretty general question.

Edit: 
Wow, I wasn't expecting this many answers to this! Sorry it took me so long to get back.
 Pretty much, all I want to do is when the user clicks on the window, a messagebox pops up - except do it from a different class than what the window procedure is in.

Example:

```
class One{
    // Other stuff

    virtual void Function() {}

    LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        // Other messages
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            Function();
            break;
    }
}

class Two : public One{
    void Function(){ MessageBoxA(0, "Hi!", "Hello", MB_OK); }
}
```

This way, I can implement this function in different ways.

Comment: Do you want the window procedure to be a virtual class member function? If so, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221815/why-cant-my-wndproc-be-in-a-class

Comment: It would have been better to show some code to illustrate the problem, say what is the *class*, how is *procedure* declared. We have to guess without any guarantee that what we understand is what you meant :-(

Comment: @Brett: It usually makes no sense to have the entire windowproc virtual. The most common action is to hand the message straight back to `DefWindowProc`, and you'd incur a needless virtual call, _plus_ you can already put in a different WndProc per window class.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: A "window procedure" in this context is a function within Microsoft Windows (which we know from `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`). Its signature is documented and very well-known. The mismatch between Windows OO and C++ OO is also a well-understood issue.

Comment: @MSalters I know what a *window procedure* is, but what means *it is a member of the same class of the procedure* ? The question cited by Brett explains that a window procedure cannot be a (non static) member function. And I also know that a window class in not the same as a C++ class ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: "(non-static)" is precisely the point. A window proc can be a static member of a class, and this is the normal technique in C++. However, static methods cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, can't (not directly): Windows expects a C function and won't provide you with a `this` pointer. However, you can store `this` using `GWLP_USERDATA`, and then retrieve it in a regular function. (using `Get/SetWindowLongPtr`). From there you can then call the virtual function.

Behind the scenes, all Windows compilers use vtables for virtual calls, but Windows can't find and won't use that vtable to make the Window procedure call.

Comment: [Related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/03/10496248.aspx); not sure how this works for virtual functions but [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx) seems to do it? The question description seems to talk about virtual functions that get called by the window procedure for each message, though...

Comment: That's indeed the same mechanism applied to a more complete example. The fancy part is passing `this` via `CreateWindowEx` to `WM_NCCREATE` and a `delete this` via `WM_NCDESTROY`. And no, that doesn't call a virtual function for each message. Raymond explains why not in another column (too slow at the time)

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting this many answers to this... How would I do it using the Get/SetWindowLongPtr method?

Comment: @AceDawg45: See the links in the first comment.

Comment: `GWLP_USERDATA` is the most unreliable place to store anything vital. It is publicly accessible and often perceived as public domain. Applications will overwrite whatever you stored there, sooner or later. Either allocate window extra space when registering the class or add a uniquely named property to the window's property list ([SetProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable: "Applications will overwrite it". The answer was written from the perspective of the application itself. Storing _your_ data attached to _other_ windows is indeed much riskier.

Comment: Storing your data into other windows' private memory is what makes storing your data in **your** window's `GWLP_USERDATA` risky. There's nothing you can do about it now, that ship has sailed. Reckless applications are out in the wild, and `GWLP_USERDATA` is unreliable. For **everyone**. It doesn't make a difference whether you are the legal owner of it or not. Simply don't use it.